# Shoot 3 bullets on set times from each enemy

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to create a simple game with kineticJS on my canvas(Just some practice) and managed to get my player to shoot bullets. The same goes for the enemies that are spawned. They shoot a bullet each time the last bullet leaves the stage.

However: I'd like all the enemies(Variable number) to shoot 3 bullets at a 2 seconds interval. But i'm stuck completely and can't figure a way how to get it done.

Could anyone please look at my fiddle and see what's up?
http://jsfiddle.net/eRQ3P/6/

Note: line 573 is the function that loops(And draws the bullets and such every 30FPS)

Here's the code where i create a new bullet object:(Line 406 in fiddle)

```
function Enemybullet(destinationX, destinationY, enemySprite) {

    this.id = 'bullet';
    this.x = enemySprite.getX()+(enemySprite.getWidth()/2);
    this.y = enemySprite.getY()+(enemySprite.getHeight()/2);

    var targetX = destinationX - this.x,
        targetY = destinationY - this.y,
        distance = Math.sqrt(targetX * targetX + targetY * targetY);

    this.velX = (targetX / distance) * 5;
    this.velY = (targetY / distance) * 5;

    this.finished = false;

    this.sprite = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y, 
        radius: 3,
        fill: 'black',
        name: 'enemyProjectile'
    });

    this.draw = function(index) {

        var mayDelete = false;

        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;

        this.sprite.setAbsolutePosition(this.x, this.y);
        //console.log(this.sprite.getX());

/*
        if(enemyCollision(this) == true) {
            mayDelete = true;
        }*/

        if (bulletLeftField(this.sprite) == true) {
            mayDelete = true;
        }

        if (mayDelete == true) {
            this.sprite.remove();
            enemies[index].bullets.splice(0, 1);
            createEnemyBullet(enemies[index]);
        }



        ammoLayer.draw();
    }
}
```

And the function providing a new bullet: (line 247 in fiddle)

```
function createEnemyBullet(enemy) {
    var blt = new Enemybullet(player.sprite.getX(), player.sprite.getY(), enemy.sprite);
    ammoLayer.add(blt.sprite);
    enemy.bullets.push(blt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the hardest part of this problem is figuring out when to draw each bullet to make three be fired in every 2-second interval. To make the bullets fire evenly, you want to divide the number of frames in the interval by the number of bullets to fire in that interval.

Because you're running the game at 30 frames per second, 2 seconds equals 60 frames.

`60 frames / 3 bullets = 20 frames/bullet`

So, we're going to create a new bullet for each enemy every 20 frames, or every 20th time `refreshLoop()` is called, and inside `refreshLoop()`, you now have to loop through all of the bullets each enemy has in its `bullets` array, because there can now be more than just one.

The fact that there can be more than one bullet in the `bullets` array introduces a new problem to the way bullets are removed from the array. Previously, you relied on the fact that one bullet at a time means it will always be the first one in the array, thus your code called `bullets.splice(0, 1);`. However, when the player is moving around and the enemies fire at the different locations, it is completely possible to have a bullet leave the screen and be removed sooner than one that was fired before it. This would cause the correct bullet sprite to be removed, but the first bullet in the array would be removed from `bullets`, so it wouldn't be updated anymore in `refreshLoop()`, and it would just sit on the screen doing nothing.

In order to avoid this, it is necessary to pass to the enemy bullets' `draw()` function the index in `bullets` at which the bullet being drawn is located. Since you need to loop through the array anyway, the index is already at hand in `refreshLoop()`, so just pass this to `draw()`. Now, every time a bullet needs to be removed, you can just call `bullets.splice(bulletIndex, 1);`

I hope you don't mind; I forked your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonhopkins/sQyJH/) to update it with the changes listed below.

**EDIT:** A new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonhopkins/sQyJH/1/) for burst-fire instead of sustained fire.

```
// Inside your Enemybullet definition
// One simple change to draw(), pass in the index of the bullet in the array
this.draw = function(indexEnemy, indexBullet) {

    var mayDelete = false;

    ...

    if (bulletLeftField(this.sprite) == true) {
        mayDelete = true;
    }

    if (mayDelete == true) {
        this.sprite.remove();

        // Since you now have multiple bullets, you'll have to make
        // sure you're removing the correct one from the array
        enemies[indexEnemy].bullets.splice(indexBullet, 1);
    }

    ammoLayer.draw();
}

...

// Inside your refreshLoop function
// If there are enemies they should be checked
if (enemies.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        enemies[i].draw();

        // At 30 frames per second, 3 bullets in 2 seconds would be
        // one bullet for every 20 frames. So, every 20 frames,
        // create a new bullet for each enemy
        if ((enemyShootTimer % 20) == 0) {
            createEnemyBullet(enemies[i]);
        }

        // The same way you draw all of the player's bullets,
        // loop through the array of bullets for this enemy,
        // and draw each one, passing in the new parameters
        if (enemies[i].bullets.length > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < enemies[i].bullets.length; j++) {
                enemies[i].bullets[j].draw(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Update loop for burst-fire instead of sustained fire
var burstTime = 10; // 10 frames between bullets, 3 per second
var needToShoot = ((enemyShootTimer % burstTime) == 0);
if (enemies.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        enemies[i].draw();

        // if the enemies still have bullets to shoot this burst
        // and if 10 frames have passed since the last shot
        // ( enemyBurstCounter is declared outside refreshLoop() )
        if (enemyBurstCounter < 3 && needToShoot) {
            createEnemyBullet(enemies[i]);
        }
        if (enemies[i].bullets.length > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < enemies[i].bullets.length; j++) {
                enemies[i].bullets[j].draw(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    if ((enemyShootTimer % 60) == 0) {
        enemyBurstCounter = 0; // if 2 seconds have passed, reset burst counter
    } else if (needToShoot) {
        enemyBurstCounter++; // if the enemies shot, update burst counter
    }
}
```

Comment: It was the timing logic which failed me in this case pretty much. It seems however that the bullets are being shot at a regular interval but not in pairs of 3 (pop, pop, pop....wait... pop, pop, pop...etc)

Comment: I was actually questioning if that might be what you wanted... I'll update with that instead.

Comment: Edited the answer with new fiddle, and added the changed code at the bottom

Comment: You're welcome. The game looks great, and I'm glad I could help improve it

Comment: While i'm at it; i came across a bug when i stop the game and empty the enemies array (`enemies = []`). The moment i call the function which stops all listeners and such i get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bullets' of undefined ` error. But if i console.log `enemies[i]` above it, it's not undefined. And using an if (`if (enemies[i].bullets){}`) around it, it still gives the error on the line of the FOR somehow... I haven't updated the fiddle because this must be just some dumb JS thing i guess :D

Comment: The only thing I can think of that's happening is the refreshLoop is working on updating the bullets when you win, but since it's already inside the loop it can't stop and hits an undefined enemy. I don't get the error though, so I'm not sure..

Comment: I've changed some things since your fiddle. I was thinking the same as you are. But it doesn't really explain how it's allowed into an if checking if the bullets are undefined or not :-p

Comment: I have no idea. Might be worth posting another question

Comment: It's updated. Line 723 in the fiddle is the one giving the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bullets' of undefined` `when youLose()` is called(line 744)

Comment: What's the url of the fiddle? It changes every time you update

Comment: I really don't know. I'll keep looking at it, but you should ask another question with this problem. It'll get the attention of people who know more about it. And it's easier to answer in an answer post rather than comments haha